# oracle unique constraint

Tags: sql, database, oracle11g

I'm trying to insert distinct values from one table into another. My target table has a primary key `studentid` and when I perform distinct `id` from source to target the load is successful. When I'm trying to load a bunch of columns from source to target including `student_id`, I'm getting an error *unique constraint violated*. There is only one constraint on target which is the primary key on `studentid`.

my query looks like this (just an example)

```
insert into target(studentid, age, schoolyear)
  select distinct id, age, 2012 from source
```

Why does the above query returns an error where as the below query  works perfectly fine

```
insert into target(studentid)
  select distinct id from source
```

help me troubleshoot this.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You need to decide _which_ of the rows to take for multiple `id`, where as pointed out in the first answer below, the other columns are _not_ distinct. You will need to perform some aggregate `MIN(),MAX()`, etc.

Comment: thank you for the reply. I understand the problem. I want unique values of id and the corresponding values for the rest of the columns. How can I achieve this. ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your **first query you are selecting for distinct combination of three columns** ie,

```
select distinct id, age, 2012 from source
```

Not the distinct id alone. In such case there are possibility for duplicate id's.
For example, Your above query is valid for this

```
id age
1   23
1   24
1   25
2   23
3   23
```

But in your **second query you are selecting only distinct id's**

```
select distinct id from source
```

So this will return like,

```
id
1
2
3
```

In this case there is no way for duplicates and your insert into target will not
fail.

If you really want to do bulk insert with constrain on target then go for
any aggregate functions

```
select id, max(age), max(2012) group by id from source
```

Or if you dont want to loose any records from source to target then remove your constraint on target and insert it.

Hope this helps

Comment: so should it be ok if I enclose id in bracekts?

Comment: If you are concerned about only id column then distinct id is perfect.

Comment: yea, I understand the problem now. So what's the correct way to deal with it. I tried this insert into target(studentid, age, schoolyear)
  select (distinct id), age, 2012 from source but i got missing expression error.

Comment: You dont want to loose any records from source to target?? I mean number of records. If you dont want to loose records then you should remove your constraint and then insert.. else you can do something like this.. am updating my answer

Comment: The problem is I want unique values of id and the corresponding values for the rest of the columns. How can I achieve this. ?

Comment: The problem is, let say I m 2 rows as like this 1 24 2012, 1 25 2012 In this case when you take unique id, either you can take '24 2012' or '25 2012'.. Do you understand??

Comment: yes that made sense. I will analyze the data that i have and that i will give me an idea as to what I can do. Thanks so much for your time.

Comment: @user1751356 yeah sure. Analyze the data and get back to us. If you found my answer as useful and proper one pls accept it. It ll be helpful for me. Thanks :) Happy new year

Comment: Yes, I did that :) Happy new year and keep rocking!